# Angular code is working fine in local machine but after hosting it on AWS S3 bucket it gives me following error:

Tags: angular, authentication, amazon-s3, version, local

```
enter code heremain.bbd2c34638e0c973.js:1 ERROR TypeError: n.auth is not a function
at main.bbd2c34638e0c973.js:1:364930
at v.invoke (polyfills.947a6f57c4e6fb39.js:1:6563)
at L.run (polyfills.947a6f57c4e6fb39.js:1:1929)
at Zs.runOutsideAngular (main.bbd2c34638e0c973.js:1:2855277)
at main.bbd2c34638e0c973.js:1:364906
at ie (main.bbd2c34638e0c973.js:1:2544)
at DB (main.bbd2c34638e0c973.js:1:364848)
at new n (main.bbd2c34638e0c973.js:1:371134)
at n.ɵfac [as factory] (main.bbd2c34638e0c973.js:1:372068)
at n0.hydrate (main.bbd2c34638e0c973.js:1:2797672)
```